# Customizing a JQuery Wizard to incorporate Partial Views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to customize a JQuery Wizard code which is currently processing static html as different steps and generating tabs like this,

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="section add-alert">
    <div class="box2">
        <div id="my-steps">

       <h3>Step 1</h3>
            <section>
        <!-- Want to replace static Content for Step 1 with a Partial View -->
    </section>

    <h3>Step 2</h3>
            <section>
        <!-- Want to replace static Content for Step 2 with a Partial View -->
    </section>

    <h3>Step 3</h3>
            <section>
        <!-- Want to replace static Content for Step 3 with a Partial View -->
    </section>

    <h3>Step 4</h3>
            <section>
        <!-- Want to replace static Content for Step 4 with a Partial View -->
    </section>

    <h3>Summary</h3>
            <section>
        <!-- Want to replace static Content for Summary with a Partial View -->
    </section>

        <div>         
    <div>
<div>
```

I am using following javascript files and css files for creating the steps and formating it.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/assets/js/app/jquery.steps.js")"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/css/jquery.steps.css")"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/css/tabs.css")" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/css/tabstyles.css")" />
```

Here is the function for creating the Steps automatically from the header tag and creating content from section tab,

```
<script>


$("#my-steps").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "fade",
    stepsOrientation: "vertical",
 });

(function () {

    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tabs')).forEach(function (el) {
        new CBPFWTabs(el);
    });

})();
```

Now what this all generate is that it creates a Wizard. On the left side there is a vertical bar on which all the tabs are created. Each tab has the name of step grabbed from the h3 tag and the content is taken from the section tag following each tag. The tabs are only clickable when the user has accessed that section. So if I am at Step 1 then Step 2 tab is not clickable. If I am at Step 2 then both Step 1 and Step 2 are clickable.

This is currently all done static and all the steps are on the same page. I have created each Step as partial view with different view model for each Step. How to implement my Partial views in this scenario?

I want to make it simple. So every Partial View will have its own form "Ajax.BeginForm" which will be pointing to its own controller method. I can handle the validation. What I don't understand is that how to use all Partial Views with this JQuery Wizard. Should I just call "@Html.Partial("Respective_Step")" under each section tag?

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? If you did, can you provide or explain how you resolved the problem.

Comment: @capiono I changed my Wizard and created it using partial views and AjaxForm in MVC. The partial views were rendered from Action Method. This approach was totally different and I was more satisfied with Partial View each rendered through Ajax call. However for JQuery type this link be quite helpful, http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/d278e8aa-3f37-40c5-92a2-74e65b1b5653.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm dealing the same problem and I have solved like this.

I make a model for all tabs and not use partial views. This wizard works fine for me.

And if you need to use partial your can send data from your model like this

```
 @Html.Partial("_EmailIndex", Model.Emails)
```

In the model you should have a property like this

```
    public List<Email> Emails { get; set; }
```

Thanks,